# php import utf-8 txt file to latin1 database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have an UTF-8 encoded txt file and I want to import it to latin1_general_ci table.
Problem is that some characters display as ? in database and not as they supposed to.

I tried mb_convert_encoding($str, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8"); but that didn't do anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latin1 doesn't include all Unicode characters. You can use [iconv()](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) with //TRANSLIT option to transliterate unknown characters to their closest latin1 equivalents:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text)
```

Comment: You might also want to determine if you'll need to escape the text for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I use [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php), it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them to binary and then convert it back to latin

```
insert into table values 
(convert(binary convert(data using utf8) using latin1))
```